# How to use cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, background-subtraction, mog, shadow-removal

I'm using OpenCV2.2 to implement moving objects detection with the method of Background Subtraction. And I use the Gaussian Mixture Model(GMM) method to model the background reference image.

I directly get the foreground pixels(or foreground mask) by using the class cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG provided in OpenCV2.2. It's convenient but the foreground mask returned by cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG is not as good as I expected. In addition, it seems that cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG performs poorer than the method of GMM wrote in C language provided in OpenCV1.0.

The following is my code in OpenCV2.2:

```
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG mog;
mog(frame, fgMask, 0.01);
```

So, did I use the method in a wrong way?

By the way, does cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG perform shadow removal on the foreground pixels?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Here's a useful overview, from 3.0 docs, of using OpenCV's Background Subtraction functions: http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you create mog, you are not defining any parameters, so it is created with default parameters. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=backgroundsubtractormog#backgroundsubtractormog-backgroundsubtractormog) you have a description of each parameter, maybe is just that. Try with 3, 4 5 Gaussians.

This function does not perforn shadow-removal but you have [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=backgroundsubtractormog#backgroundsubtractormog2-backgroundsubtractormog2) other function that does. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

There are recent algorithms which remove backgrounds (detect foreground) far better than the standard GMM implementation in OpenCV.

For example, there is a block-based classifier cascade approach described in [this journal article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.4160v1.pdf), along with its C++ based [source code](http://arma.sourceforge.net/foreground/).

Comment: What should the input directory structure look like for using this tool? It seems to segfault on readdir() no matter what I throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

F.X.'s answer on [this thread](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/emgucv-detect-a-ball-in-the-frame/3342#3342) gives sample parameters of

```
backgroundSubtractor = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG(3, 4, 0.8);
```

Comment: but that's running very slowly on my app. i'm on the lookout for some good parameters myself

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using the following settings to get started. Then you can start tuning your parameters:

```
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog;
mog(rawFrame,foregroundFrame,-1);
mog.set("nmixtures", 3);
mog.set("detectShadows",1);
```

In this example I set the MOG2 subtractor with 3 Gaussian mixtures. I also enabled shadow detection.