# getBackgroundImage fails with BackgroundSubtractorMOG

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to retrieve the BackgroundImage from BackgroundSubtractorMOG with the function [getBackgroundImage().](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=background#backgroundsubtractor-getbackgroundimage)

Unfortunately I always get an empty matrix.

Is this behaviour a bug in OpenCV2.4.8 or do I mabye have to do some kind of additional initilization? (If you switch from MOG to MOG2 it works fine.)

Current initialization inspired by [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458633/how-to-use-cvbackgroundsubtractormog-in-opencv)

Sample Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    BackgroundSubtractorMOG mog(3, 4, 0.8);
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

    cv::Mat frame, backMOG, foreMOG;
    for(;;){
        cap >> frame;

        mog(frame, foreMOG,-1);
        cv::imshow("foreMOG", foreMOG);

        mog.getBackgroundImage(backMOG);
        if(!backMOG.empty()){
            cv::imshow("backMOG", backMOG); //never reached
        }

        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: afaik it isn't implemented in the latest source code. Have a look at the sources to verify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Micka pointed correctly out in the comment: It's just not implemented!

A call of `mog.getBackgroundImage(backMOG);` jumps to

`void BackgroundSubtractor::getBackgroundImage(OutputArray) const {}`

in file `bgfg_gaussmix2.cpp`.

Long story short: `BackgroundSubtractorGMG` and `BackgroundSubtractorMOG` don't implement `getBackgroundImage` currently in OpenCV 2.4.8. Only `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` supports it.